# Initialize UISegmentedControl storyboard index

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

**EDIT**

Maybe I have described the problem incorrectly. Let me add that this segmented controller is controlling the speed of a `NSTimer` with the following code.

```
- (IBAction) segmentAction:(id)sender
{
    speed = [[speeds objectAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]] integerValue];
}

- (IBAction)startPause: (UIButton *)sender{
    NSString *buttonTitle = sender.currentTitle;
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString: @"Pause"]) {

        [self.myButton setTitle:@"Resume" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.myButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if ([self.deal length]>cardNum) {
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speed
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(dealCard)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [timer invalidate];
        }
    }
}
```

When the user taps any of the segments in the segmentedController BEFORE tapping the `startPause` button, the NSTimer works fine. Nut if the user taps the `startPause` button before tapping a segment, no (desired) delays occur from the NSTimer. Does this help explain the situation any better?

**EDIT**

I have a UISegmentedControl in Storyboard and want to initialize it. It would be especially nice to initialize it in the Storyboard itself. The image below shows how the Med segment is selected, but when the app starts, Med is NOT selected; rather the user has to trigger a `Value changed` event. How do I get it selected, initially? One of the other questions here on SO suggested the following code, but I have not figured out how to associate the UISegmentedControl in my Storyboard with the name `segmentControl`.

`segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex=-1;`

[image: Storyboard view of control]